# Making a trajectory plot using R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to make a trajectory plot of my data set, like a scatterplot of X,Y but the data points are connected with a line using an arrow (where the arrow points to the next position)

My data looks like this:

```
A    T   X     Y      V      GD  ND   ND2 TID
1 1 3.88 2.7 675.0 27.000  27.000  NA    NA  t1
2 1 3.92 2.7 677.7 42.691  69.691 2.7  7.29  t1
3 1 3.96 2.7 675.0 55.662 125.353 0.0  0.00  t1
4 1 4.00 2.7 675.0 55.662 181.015 0.0  0.00  t1
5 1 4.04 2.7 675.0 55.662 236.677 0.0  0.00  t1
6 1 4.08 2.7 680.4 42.691 279.368 5.4 29.16  t1
```

And I have tried using qplot to make it:

```
qplot(X, Y, data = sub.data1, color = TID, group = TID)+ 
  geom_line(linetype=5, size=1.5, arrow=arrow(angle=15, ends="both", type="closed"))+
  geom_point (shape=19, size=5, fill="black")
```

This was okay, it worked. Just that I wanted to make the points in my plot arrows that are pointing in the next data point.
Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to explore the geom_path and geom_segment attributes. See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_segment.html
and
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_path.html

For example, I can take your plot and simply change the line to a path to connect the dots in the order that they are presented in your table rather than by the X axis:

```
library("ggplot2")
library(grid) # needed for arrow function
library(data.table)
# see http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_segment.html
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),T=c(3.88,3.92,3.96,4.00,4.04,4.08),X=c(2.7,2.9,2.7,2.0,2.7,2.0),Y=c(675.0,600.7,675.0,690.0,675.0,680.4),V=c(27.0,42,55,55,55,42),GD=c(27,70,125,181,236,279),ND=c(NA,2.7,0,0,0,5.4),ND2=c(NA,7,0,0,0,29.2),TID="t1")
qplot(X, Y, data = df, color = TID, group = TID)+ 
        geom_path(linetype=5, size=1.5, arrow=arrow(angle=15, ends="both", type="closed"))+
        geom_point (shape=19, size=5, fill="black")
```

Comment: My code worked in making a plot but I would like my plot to have arrows instead of dots as connecting points. And these arrows should be pointing to the next. Something like this (http://humanflowerproject.com/images/uploads/Darwin-Plant-Movement-Plot3.jpg). Thanks!

Comment: Ah I understand now, +1. I'll see what I can do--I might not have a chance to take a crack at it today, but with this information, and link, I think you should get a good response.

Comment: Found the neat, geom_path function that might help out. I edited my answer to reflect the refinement of your question.

Comment: Hi @Docuemada, I also tried geom_path, the problem with it is that it connects all points together (which is kind of confusing). But thanks!

Comment: Hi @Kaye11, I can't access your link to see a picture (might be a block on my end), so I'm just kind of guessing. So you only want arrows? If so, set linetype=0.